# Deep watch doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

Have plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/hdstMO7BDGGsNRUDJhQS?p=preview

Deep watching fires when change 'name' or 'surname', but doesn't fire when change 'phones'. Why? How can i watch full object or how to do this in angular-way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
<span contenteditable ng-model="phone">{{ phone }}</span>
```

Since the phones is an array of primitive values, `ngRepeat` will create a copy of each phone on a scope created by `ngRepeat`. Then your `ngModel` is bound to this copy so the original object isn't changed and this is why your deep watch doesn't fire.

The remedy is simple, change the line in question to

```
<span contenteditable ng-model="contact.phones[$index]">{{ phone }}</span>
```

and you should be set: http://plnkr.co/edit/dxKBw3uZqSA4mfCDU2h1?p=preview